# Unable to change brightness via nvidia-settings nor brightness keys

Tags: nvidia, macbook-pro

I'm using a MacBook Pro Mid-2010 13-inch.

Sorry for the double post, but I didn't notice attention to the original and I need help with the issue badly :|

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`sudo setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0`

If it works, they add it to `/etc/rc.local` (without the sudo)

Comment: Should I replace 00:01.00 with the PCI ID of my bridge/display? My bridge is 00:17.0 and display is 04:00.0.